# Call WCF service form Dotnet Core

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core

I am using a WCF service with custom binding, I set the gzip for decrease the length of my result. Recently we migrate to .NET Core and after I call my method in core project I got this error

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to `http://www.???.com:96/TicketCache.svc/mex`. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

after I changed my config in wcf and set it to basic binding, it worked fine

I searched a lot and test different way, but I couldn't answer

```
BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement binaryMessageEncodingBindingElement = new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement();

binaryMessageEncodingBindingElement.CompressionFormat = CompressionFormat.GZip;

HttpTransportBindingElement httpTransportBindingElement = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
httpTransportBindingElement.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536000;
httpTransportBindingElement.MaxBufferSize = 65536000;

CustomBinding customBinding = null;
customBinding = new CustomBinding( new BindingElement[] { binaryMessageEncodingBindingElement, httpTransportBindingElement });
customBinding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
customBinding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
customBinding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
customBinding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
customBinding.CreateBindingElements();

var factory = new ChannelFactory<customBinding, new EndpointAddress("http://www.???.com:96/TicketCache.svc/mex"));
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is the service up and running, and is firewall access granted?

Comment: I allowed the service in firewall and open it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is .net core issue, I fixed the problem by installing visual studio 2017. you should uninstall it and then install latest version of net core. currently is 1.1.2

Comment: It worked for me, but do you have any way to work with out changing the .net core version ?

Comment: yes, this is a bug happening due to "Data Contract" problem. but I`am not sure if it would be fixed with another solution

Comment: I test it on other system with VS2017 and .net core 1.1.1 and it worked, I am so confused

Comment: after different tests , I found its about OS, It works fine with win 10 and has problem on win 7, I have on idea why it is happen

Answer (score -1):

Add code like below to web.config

```
<behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
       <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
        <defaultPorts> <!— Use your own port numbers —>
           <add scheme="http" port="enter your web service port :8088" />
         </defaultPorts>
       </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
```

Comment: my problem is about .netCore project , it works fine with .netframwork project and its not about my web service